# Two event handlers clicking each other, without endless loop?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

New user here, trying to learn something that I reckon is pretty basic. But I've run into this scenario where I wanted to populate a list of google map markers from an array already prepared.

So what I wanted to do was to zoom in on the marker in the map, as well as highlight the corresponding element in the list. And let both the map marker and the list element be clickable, and do the same thing. Clicking each other. Without them looping forever.

In this case, I ran independent functions for each handler that did the actual work. And that's the correct way of doing it. But it made me think of how poorly I understand logical operators.

Instead of throwing in all the code here, I've simplified it to these basics and created a CodePen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amiuy

Here's the code as well:

Html:

```
<div id="button1">Button 1</div>
<div id="button2">Button 2</div>

<ul id="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked button 1');
    $(this).css('color', 'red');

    $('#button2').trigger('click');
    populateList('button1');

});

$(document).on('click', '#button2', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked button 2');
    $(this).css('color', 'button');

    $('#button1').trigger('click');
    populateList('button2');

});

function populateList (button) {
    var list = $_('#list');
    list.append('<li>New item from: ' + button + '</li>')
}
```

I know I can solve this by creating variables for each click handler, setting it to true or false accordingly. But it's this logic that I'm having trouble with. When should they be set to true and when should they be set to false?

Edit: I also understand that I should run functions in click handlers, and let the two click handlers run the same functions, not triggering each other. But this is just the basic understanding of logical operators I guess. I just need to learn this, regardless of this example being stupid. Because I might run into scenarios similar to this in the future. And these things always throw me off.

Comment: Why on earth do you want the logic of having each button click the other? You should have both button clicks call an independent function, or have just the list item click call the marker click (and not vice versa too).

Comment: Yeah, I just updated my question with exactly that. :) I know I should never do this, but it's the basic logical operators I want to learn, not this exact scenario. The google maps scenario was solved that way. The two click handlers ran the same independent functions.